# Is it possible in Swift 4.2 to write a default extension to an enum with rawValue of a specific type?

Tags: swift, enums

I am refactoring code to Swift 4.2 that parses a binary stream. I am using a protocol to read values from a data object.

```
public protocol DataExchangable {
    init(from data:Data, at pos: inout Int) throws
    var data:Data { get }
}
```

I have written extensions to numeric datatypes, eg. UInt16 that make these types conform to the protocol.

Part of the stream-data are various type id's which so far are represented as enum. For example:

```
public enum FormatID: UInt16 {
    case PNG = 0x0000, DPX, JPG, TIF
}
```

I do have a whole bunch of these and I could extend each enum individually to conform to the protocol, but it would be much more efficient to be able to define a default extension for all enums.

I have tried:

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue:DataExchangable {
    public init(from data: Data, at pos: inout Int) throws {
        let u16 = UInt16(from: data, at:&pos)
        self.init(rawValue: u16)
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the code does not let me call the enum initializer with a UInt16, despite the fact UInt16 conforms with the CAPDataExchangeable.

I am not sure what I am trying to do is possible? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supplying a concrete type `UInt16` within a broader extension i.e. `RawRepresentable....etc`. So replace `UInt16` with `RawValue`.

Also since the `self.init` is failable you need your extension initializer to also be failable.

The code below compiles

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue: DataExchangable {
    public init?(from data: Data, at pos: inout Int) throws {
        let dataExchangeValue = try RawValue(from: data, at: &pos)
        self.init(rawValue: dataExchangeValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I could have thought about this myself! :/ - Perfect! The code so far uses Errors instead of Optional values to handle parsing error, so I am going to add a guard statement to throw an error when the initializer fails - hence the throws clause in the protocol.